# Dovecot stops with No passdbs specified in configuration file error

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm working with Dovecot and Postfix but recently I tried to use Postfixadmin ([following this references](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfixadmin-create-virtual-mailboxes-debian#comment-747116)). Regardless Postfixadmin works normally, when somebody try to login via Outlook or Thunderbird with an existent email account, the Dovecot service stops with the following error:

```
Jul 20 16:12:41 email-server systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jul 20 16:12:41 email-server dovecot[28856]: master: Dovecot v2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4) starting up for imap, lmtp, imap, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/libdriver_mysql.so
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: auth: Fatal: No passdbs specified in configuration file. LOGIN mechanism needs one
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28856]: master: Error: service(auth): command startup failed, throttling for 2 secs
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: imap-login: Disconnected: Auth process broken (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=187.208.178.229, 
Jul 20 16:12:56 email-server dovecot[28858]: imap-login: Warning: Timeout leak: 0x7f112d1aa730 (auth-server-connection.c:397)
```

Regardless my `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext` file contains already the following code my Dovecot continue crashing with the same error:

```
passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}

userdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you edited, `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext`, is *optionally included* from another configuration file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`, usually commented out but ready to be activated. The default `dovecot.conf` includes only the additional config files ending in `.conf`, the `.ext` snippet files are usually optional components or extensions of those `.conf` files.

Comment out other unwanted auth-related includes, and make the commented include statement (`#!include ..`) a real include  (`!include ..`)

---

When uncertain of any configuration file interpretation, use `doveconf` to print *effective* configuration, that should clarify any perceived mismatch between file content and Dovecot program behaviour.

Comment: Very well, I've commented out `!include auth-sql.conf.ext` from `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf` which was causing the Dovecot crashing and now it works! Thank you!